# How to implement __setitem__ to set attributes of a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, dictionary

my classes

```
class Base:
    #has no attributes of its own

    def __init__(self, params):
        for key in params:
            if hasattr(self, key):
                self[key] = params[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value



class Child(Base):
    prop1 = None
    prop2 = None
```

This however, goes into endless recursion as `self[key] = value` recursively calls `self.__setitem__`

My goal is to be able to pass a a dictionary into a `Child()` constructor like this

```
params = dict(
    prop1 = "one",
    prop2 = "two"
)
c = Child(params)

c.prop1     #"one"
c.prop2     #"two"
```

There are many different classes like Child but with different fields. `params` is a dict from a json blob. I want to use `Base` as a generic populator for the different classes like `Child`

I have seen methods that use an internal `dict` to accomplish what I am asking but it is my understand (I am brand new to Python) that this would prevent accessing the methods via dot notation (which I would rather avoid).

Comment: given the `hasattr` your requirements are more complex than you suggest. Inside the child you have some class level attributes `prop1` and `prop2` but are trying to initialize `field1` and `field2`, are these supposed to differ?

Comment: Do you know the difference between class and instance attributes?

Comment: sorry they should have been "propX". edited

Comment: @martineau I assume class attributes are how I currently define them in `Child` and instance are those set by `self.whatever = ...`

Comment: @thedarklord47: While what you say in your response it true, it (as well as the answer you accepted) seem to indicate that you don't really understand how the two differ from one another in other, more important, ways.

Comment: like what? I am new to python and would like to do things correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the `__dict__` of the instance in your `__init__`:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, params):
        for key in params:
            if hasattr(type(self), key):
                self.__dict__[key] = params[key]
```

Then:

```
class Child(Base):
    field1 = None
    field2 = None

c = Child(dict(field1="one", field2="two", field3="three"))

print(c.field1)     # "one"
print(c.field2)     # "two"
print(c.field3)     # => attr error
```

Grandchildren will behave:

```
class GrandChild(Child):
    field3 = None

gc = GrandChild(dict(field1="one", field2="two", field3="three"))

print(gc.field1)     # "one"
print(gc.field2)     # "two"
print(gc.field3)     # "three"
```

Comment: this would not work with `__slots__` but that's probably outside what OP needs

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can imagine to what you want involves using `setattr`, which takes an object, an attribute name (as a `str`) and a value for that attribute.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        for k, v in params.iteritems():
            if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v)

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.field1 = None  # create attributes here, not at class level
        self.field2 = None
        Base.__init__(self, params)

params = dict(
    field1 = "one",
    field2 = "two",
    field3 = "tree", # ignored when used with Child since it has no field3
)
c = Child(params)
```